# Click in a image/function with javascript on Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey

How can I click in a image/function with javascript?

Something like:

```
document.getElementById("check-in-banner").click();
```

the source of the part is

```
<a id="check-in-button" href="#">
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById("check-in-button");
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
```